# Call for action: realistic map wiki

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I have noticed that quite often we get questions along the line of "I am creating my world, I have come up with a map, does it make sense?"

You can find a list [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=map%20realistic)

These questions do rarely get closed, however I find that they often revolve around some basic concepts which could be better handled in a wiki sort of answer.

Therefore this call for action: if you have the time do so, would you start this wiki where we could collectively "dump" our knowledge time after time?

**Update**

I have started the wiki [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/227640/30492), feel free to chip in

Comment: They probably should be closed. Similar to how Stack Overflow doesn't support questions asking for people to just review code and offer open ended suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: I understand 'does my map make sense' as synonymous with 'Reality Check: this is what my world looks like and how it operates'. Most of them focus on tectonics, oceanic currents, winds, and general ecosystems. I think a wiki answer could be very useful.

Comment: How should one do this? Write a new question & answer and wiklify that?

Comment: This answer [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/102798/how-do-i-figure-out-my-planets-biomes-and-weather/102838#102838) would probably be a useful resource for such questions. I'd best disclose now that I wrote that answer myself, but as far as I know it's been considered very helpful as a guide.

Comment: @elemtilas that seems reasonable

Comment: I'll give a shot at filling in that wiki answer. It's likely to seem long-winded to readers, but lesson #1 is that realistic maps take a lot of attention to detail.